# need help in understanding a code

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can anyone explain this code a little. I can't understand what `n` does here? We already have taken `N = int(input())` as input then why `n=len(bin(N))-2`? I couldn't figure it out.

```
N = int(input())
n = len(bin(N))-2
for i in range(1,N+1):
    print(str(i).rjust(n) + " " + format(i,'o').rjust(n) + " " + format(i,'X').rjust(n) + " " + format(i,'b').rjust(n))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`n` counts the number of *bits* in the number `N`. `bin()` produces the binary representation (zeros and ones), as as string with the `0b` prefix:

```
>>> bin(42)
'0b101010'
```

so `len(bin(n))` takes the length of that output string, minus 2 to account for the prefix.

See the [`bin()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin):

> Convert an integer number to a binary string prefixed with “0b”.

The length is used to set the width of the columns (via [`str.rjust()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust), which adds spaces to the front of a string to create an output `n` characters wide). Knowing how many characters the widest binary representation needs is helpful here.

However, the same information can be gotten *directly* from the number, with the [`int.bitlength()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length):

```
>>> N = 42
>>> N.bit_length()
6
>>> len(bin(N)) - 2
6
```

The other columns are also oversized for the numbers. You could instead calculate max widths for each column, and use `str.format()` or an f-string to do the formatting:

```
from math import log10

N = int(input())
decwidth = int(log10(N) + 1)
binwidth = N.bit_length()
hexwidth = (binwidth - 1) // 4 + 1
octwidth = (binwidth - 1) // 3 + 1

for i in range(1, N + 1):
    print(f'{i:>{decwidth}d} {i:>{octwidth}o} {i:>{hexwidth}X} {i:>{binwidth}b}')
```